# Unexplainable behaviour when integrating x86 FreeRTOS port (pthreads) and auxilary pthreads code

Tags: c, gdb, pthreads, valgrind, freertos

I am out of ideas of how to figure out where my problem is coming from.

I am trying to incorporate a Async UDP handler into an existing FreeRTOS emulator, both being pthreads based. The FreeRTOS implementation is essentially a wrapper around pthreads and the UDP handler spawns a FreeRTOS task which then spawns a pthread thread for each socket, such that the spawned threads can have their own sigaction to handle that specific UDP port with a specified callback.

As a sanity check I moved the UDP handler code into a stand alone build yesterday to test it and it works without fault, found [here](https://github.com/alxhoff/C-code-snippets/tree/master/async_UDP_multithread). All valgrind checks also showing no errors. The FreeRTOS Emulator is also stable when the UDP handler is not added, found [here](https://github.com/alxhoff/FreeRTOS-Emulator). The unstable integration can be found [here](https://github.com/alxhoff/FreeRTOS-Emulator/tree/async).

Now when integrating the two I get behavior I have not been able to debug successfully yet. The bug presents itself as a heisenbug in that during debugging I am not able to recreate it always. All valgrind (memcheck, helgrind and drd) are not able to recreate the bug, only reporting errors in linked libraries such as SDL2, X11, mensa graphics etc. Post morten GDB is able to capture the fault as well as when using `(gdb) set disable-randomization off`.

The backtrace from gdb shows me the following

> (gdb) bt
>
> #0  0x00007faa2f45a41b in pthread_kill () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
>
> #1  0x0000564392f5c93b in prvResumeThread (xThreadId=0) at /home/alxhoff/git/GitHub/FreeRTOS-Emulator/lib/FreeRTOS_Kernel/portable/GCC/Posix/port.c:561
>
> #2  0x0000564392f5c38b in vPortYield () at /home/alxhoff/git/GitHub/FreeRTOS-Emulator/lib/FreeRTOS_Kernel/portable/GCC/Posix/port.c:329
>
> #3  0x0000564392f5d986 in xQueueGenericReceive (xQueue=0x564396692bd0, pvBuffer=0x0, xTicksToWait=4294967295, xJustPeeking=0) at /home/alxhoff/git/GitHub/FreeRTOS-Emulator/lib/FreeRTOS_Kernel/queue.c:1376
>
> #4  0x0000564392f5b0d3 in vDemoTask1 (pvParameters=0x0) at /home/alxhoff/git/GitHub/FreeRTOS-Emulator/src/main.c:338
>
> #5  0x0000564392f5c754 in prvWaitForStart (pvParams=0x5643966b2780) at /home/alxhoff/git/GitHub/FreeRTOS-Emulator/lib/FreeRTOS_Kernel/portable/GCC/Posix/port.c:496
>
> #6  0x00007faa2f4524cf in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
>
> #7  0x00007faa2efcd2d3 in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

The problem appears to be that `prvResumeThread` is not being passed a valid thread id as seen in #1. Going into the FreeRTOS sources I believe that this should not be the case as the same threads are created when the UDP handler and it's respective task are added, their addition somehow leads to FreeRTOS's `pxCurrentTCB` becoming invalid when executing `xTaskGetCurrentTaskHandle` which retrieves the thread handle for the faulting `prvResumeThread` call in #1 of the backtrace. Moving the task creation order around leads to the same error which makes me think I am dealing with some sort of memory leak but given that I cannot reproduce the error with valgrind I am unsure of how to diagnose the error.

I am worried this seems like a "debug my program" post but I am unsure of what methods or tools I can utilize to further my diagnosis, given my limited experience with multi-threaded debugging, and am in need of a push in the right direction.

Cheers

Comment: Perhaps it is just poorly worded, but "the spawned threads can have their own sigaction to handle that specific UDP port with a specified callback" suggests a possible misunderstanding.  Signal dispositions are attributes of *whole processes*.  Individual threads do not get their own signal dispositions.  Possibly, though, the UDP server installs a (one) handler for some signal, and that calls callback functions registered on a per-thread basis.

Comment: Hmm, adding to John Billinger: I am only familiar with the Linux implementation of POSIX, and not sure which signals you want to react to and in which manner. But be aware of that within signal handlers, basically invoking any system call (esp. IO related) is highly dangerous. I am not really sure what guarantess there are, and whether the things you are allowed to depend on the signals captured. Just be aware that signals are tricky. For most of the stuff you want to do via signals, there are other options. And any option is better than using signals.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think I did word it porly. Also this Async handler is the result of a programing exercise I set for myself to learn signals, so I am far from proficient. For each socket opened I am creating a pthread and an entry in a list where the relation between a port, it's file descriptor and callback is store. Each time the sigaction is triggered this list is searched and the appropriate callback is called, passing in the received data. I use fcntl with F_SETOWN and gettid() but after what you have said this seems like the wrong thing to do.

Comment: I think that's overstating it a bit @MichaelBeer.  Many of the basic POSIX I/O functions are async signal safe, thus not *inherently* unsafe to call from a signal handler.  Moreover, what you can or should do in a signal handler typically does depend on the reason the signal was generated, and which signal it is may convey information about that, but different signal numbers do not inherently place different requirements on what a handler may do.  On this we agree, however: signals are tricky, there are often other alternatives, and almost any viable alternative is perferable to signals.

Comment: My opting for using signals was the ability to have async IO such that FreeRTOS could just chug along quietly until UDP traffic appears. I am not quite understanding how the UDP threads could affect the FreeRTOS threads, especially as the RTOS threads do not have any dependencies on SIGIO which I am using in my UDP handling.

Comment: @AlexHoffmann, your signal-handling might not be related to the issue, but it *does* sound suspicious.  Signal handlers are typically called with a very small stack, and there are significant limitations on what functions may be called within their scope.  Signal handlers should do as little as possible and return as quickly as possible, but one of the tricks is that the exact limits are unspecified, and no way to determine dynamically when you are approaching them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I dont think it is my signal handling as my program faults almost straight away, before I even send any traffic to the port via netcat. All that is being done is [this](https://github.com/alxhoff/C-code-snippets/blob/b04baa3a7778c28748638690c7c62298acc806b9/async_UDP_multithread/src/main.c#L219) which I think is quite minimal. It appears to be stable when executed not in conjunction with the RTOS potion of the program.

Comment: You should be able to rule out a signal handling problem by having the main thread block the relevant signal before it starts any other threads.  New threads inherit their signal mask (which *is* a per-thread attribute) from their parent.  If the signal is blocked for all threads then the handler will never be invoked.

Comment: Have you tried running the program under a memory-usage analyzer, such as Valgrind's "memcheck"?  Or a thread-usage analyzer, such as Valgrind's "helgrind" or "DRD"?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yep I have tried all three as I mentioned in my post. Sadly the fault does not appear in valgrind.

Comment: @JohnBollinger unrelated as it does not seem to fix my problem but your original comment about signals has made me discover a flaw in my signal handling logic as I thought each thread would get its own signal disposition. Thanks for the useful info.

Comment: Well then, I've got nothing more to suggest with regard to tools.  Since the issue manifests quickly upon starting the program, though, you can try to narrow down the problem by seeing what code is essential for it to manifest, and what can be removed.  Of course, this is one of the main approaches to preparing a [mre], and that's not coincidental.  From the look of it, you're unlikely to get the program down to anything suitable for posting here, but this was a good general debugging technique long before SO ever existed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I believe I have found the line responsible funnily enough. Appears that me creating the extra pthreads (because of my assumption that each thread has its own signal disposition) is causing the issue. Maybe somehow the extra threads not created using the FreeRTOS api are corrupting FreeRTOS's thread management. Either way, your suggestion has narrowed it down so thanks!

Comment: The FreeRTOS x86 port is at best FreeRTOS-like. It performs context switches by starting and stopping a number of pthreads and trying to ensure that these threads are never running at the same time.

All of the code assumes that at any time there is only a single thread of execution and that the scheduler is in control of it all.

It is not reasonable to create additional threads in your application that have any level of interaction with the FreeRTOS code, especially calling any FreeRTOS API's which would touch the TCB's.

Comment: So perhaps I can summarize that the FreeRTOS x86 port USES pthreads but is in no way compatible with you using pthreads in your application. The assumption is that if you need multi-threading you will use FreeRTOS tasks and only FreeRTOS primitives just like pthreads and signals (things from another OS) did not exist.